# Expose WSDL over i-jetty on Android

Tags: android, wsdl, service-reference, ijetty, java2wsdl

I want to use android as a web service that expose WSDL, that I will be able to "Add service reference" in Visual Studio.

I need to build a web service on android, I checked [i-jetty](https://code.google.com/p/i-jetty/) for that, and the solution might work,

How to expose WSDL over i-jetty

(I will use android over a LAN and it will always be connected to power supply so web-service is the right solution, I just need it to work similar to WCF service)

Thanks!
Izhar.